# Redstone Ore Giving Nothing When Mined

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I'm finding that when I break Redstone blocks while mining I am getting nothing in return. I've read this happens on PE but I'm using the PC version(Windows 7), which I downloaded yesterday. I am in survival mode. Has anyone experienced this? I've mined about 10 of these and have gotten nothing. From what I've read every one of those blocks should have given me something, it doesn't appear to be a rare drop. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of pickaxe are you using? Iron and above is necessary for redstone.

Comment: [Block of Redstone](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Block_of_Redstone) or [Redstone Ore](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_Ore)?

Comment: @AlvinWong 99.9% certain the OP means Redstone Ore, else the comments about mining and knowing this happens on PE wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using a Stone Pickaxe, which is what I almost exclusively use for tunneling, it will not yield any Redstone dust - it will simply destroy the block.

Use an iron or diamond pickaxe; you'll find that not only will it increase the mining speed of redstone ore, you'll actually get the redstone dust in return.

Comment: Why are youing stone?  It is sloowwww.

Comment: @zoredache It's the least expensive way to mine. I do the same. As you're mining you're replacing the resources needed to build a new pick axe. Iron isn't rare but it isn't as readily available as stone. Usually if I'm going on a major expedition I bring several stone pickaxes and one iron one, which I have enchanted for durability and efficiency, and use that in the case of Redstone and other things that don't drop resources  from Stone Pickaxes.

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen, Iron, is plentiful.  I have never went on a resource expedition with an iron pick and not ended up with enough iron to make 3-4 more.  Plus you collect resources a lot faster, which usually means you get more resources per-hour.  So use iron, or preferably diamond, because you will end up more resources in a play session, because you were able to mine more blocks.

Comment: @zoredache I guess I just feel there are better things to spend iron on than making pickaxes.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what type of Pickaxe you are using. If you are using stone, it will not give you anything. You have to use an Iron or Diamond pickaxe. I have made this mistake before. Redstone will not give you anything no matter what Pickaxe you're using if it is Minecraft Pocket Edition.